# HTTPS not working in Netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, https, ssl-certificate

I am creating a web application in [Netbeans 7.4](https://netbeans.org/) and I am using [Apache Tomcat 7.0.41.0](http://tomcat.apache.org/) as web server. When I created war file of my app, deploy in `Tomcat` outside `Netbeans` and run app in https://localhost:8443/MIS and app worked. But when I run app from `Netbeans` then `Netbeans` automatically redirect to `https` and browser display `This webpage is not available`. I created my certificate for my application by using [Java keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html).

My `web.xml` is look like following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>readCert</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>readCert</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>readCert</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/readCert</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>This app requires authentication</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>

        <user-data-constraint>
            <!-- transport-guarantee can be CONFIDENTIAL, INTEGRAL, or NONE -->
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

My `server.xml` is look like following:

```
    <Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="D:\misCert.crt" keystorePass="123456"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What URL appears in the browser after NetBeans launches the app?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When I run app from Netbeans it is automatically redirect to https://localhost:8443/MIS/. MIS is my app name

Comment: In your OP you said the app was called `MyAppName`.  In any case, you really should have posted your web.xml file, which might immediately explain what is going wrong here.

Comment: Ok I will change and add whole web.xml

Comment: When you say that it worked running outside in Tomcat, what do you mean?  What page did you see?

Comment: I clean and build my app and get mis.war. After getting war file I stopped apache tomcat in netbens. Copy Paste mis.war to tomcat webapps folder and start tomcat from bin folder. And my app work.

Comment: You need to configure NetBeans to launch to this location: `https://localhost:8443/MIS/readCert` ... I have never used NetBeans extensively, so I cannot give you a better answer than this.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I created `https://localhost:8443/MIS/readCert` as home page. I thing problem is with netbeans but not exactly I do not know what is problem.